# how to input sentences into HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, translate

I have a program that is supposed to translate English into a made-up language, like elvish.

my first idea was to use hashmaps
but of course, I can't do,

```java
map.get("Hello, I am human");
```

and have it check "Hello", "i", "am", "a", "human" and then translate that into "Hallo, ich bin ein Mensch" or "dragon, robot cat whale horse"

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it might not be exactly what you want, but this is how I approached this. There's likely a better way to do this (I'm thinking regex or something) but I don't know how to do that so this is the best I've got.

- Gather the input sentences
- Split up the words
- If the word is in the conversion map:
- Retrieve the converted word and add to an array

  ```
  ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("hello world", "this is a test"));
  HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

  map.put("hello", "wordForHello");
  map.put("world", "wordForWorld");
  map.put("this", "wordForThis");
  map.put("is", "wordForIs");
  map.put("a", "wordForA");
  map.put("test", "wordForTest");

  ArrayList<String> sentence = new ArrayList<>();

  for (String str : strings) {
      String[] words = str.split(" ");
      for (String word : words) {
          if (map.containsKey(word)) {
              sentence.add(map.get(word));
          }
      }
      System.out.println(sentence);
      sentence = new ArrayList<>();
  }
  ```